# Rename files in bash based on content inside

Tags: bash

I have a directory which has 70000 xml files in it. Each file has a tag which looks something like this, for the sake of simplicity:
`<ns2:apple>, <ns2:orange>, <ns2:grapes>, <ns2:melon>`. Each file has only one fruit tag, i.e. there cannot be both apple and orange in the same file.

I would like rename every file (add "1_" before the beginning of each filename) which has one of: `<ns2:apple>, <ns2:orange>, <ns2:melon>` inside of it.

I can find such files with egrep:

```
egrep -r '<ns2:apple>|<ns2:orange>|<ns2:melon>'
```

So how would it look as a bash script, which I can then user as a cron job?

P.S. Sorry I don't have any bash script draft, I have very little experience with it and the time is of the essence right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be done with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
find /path/to/directory/with/xml -type f | while read f; do
    grep -q -E '<ns2:apple>|<ns2:orange>|<ns2:melon>' "$f" && mv "$f" "1_${f}"
done
```

But it will rescan the directory each time it runs and append 1_ to each file containing one of your tags. This means a lot of excess IO and files with certain tags will be getting 1_ prefix each run, resulting in names like 1_1_1_1_file.xml.

Probably you should think more on design, e.g. move processed files to two directories based on whether file has certain tags or not:

```
#!/bin/sh

# create output dirs
mkdir -p /path/to/directory/with/xml/with_tags/ /path/to/directory/with/xml/without_tags/

find /path/to/directory/with/xml -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f | while read f; do
    if grep -q -E '<ns2:apple>|<ns2:orange>|<ns2:melon>'; then
        mv "$f" /path/to/directory/with/xml/with_tags/
    else
        mv "$f" /path/to/directory/with/xml/without_tags/
    fi
done
```

Comment: What if I check the filename, whether if it starts with "1_"? How would the first script look then ?

Comment: It would be like this (sorry for 1liner, it's a comment so no fancy formatting):

find /path/to/directory/with/xml -type f -not -name '1_*'| while read f; do grep -q -E '<ns2:apple>|<ns2:orange>|<ns2:melon>' "$f" && mv "$f" "1_${f}"; done

Answer (score 0):

Run this command as a dry run, then remove `--dry_run` to actually rename the files:

```
grep -Pl '(<ns2:apple>|<ns2:orange>|<ns2:melon>)' *.xml | xargs rename --dry-run 's/^/1_/'
```

The command-line utility `rename` comes in many flavors. Most of them should work for this task. I used the [`rename`](https://github.com/ap/rename) version 1.601 by Aristotle Pagaltzis. To install `rename`, simply download its Perl script and place into `$PATH`. Or install `rename` using `conda`, like so:

```
conda install rename
```

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-l` : Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)